# Is is possible to call a variable that has been assigned after the call (PHP)?

Tags: php, variables

The title is in the question (EDIT: :P I mean the question is in the title), basically can I call variable $x before defining it further down the page?

Comment: Call an undefined variable to do what? It will trigger warnings, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure to understand your point but if you want to write

```
echo $x;
$x = "2";
```

you will not get "2" as a result.

PHP will usually not issue a warning when you reference a variable that has not yet been assigned a value. PHP will create it on the fly and assign it the *null* value which will then be casted to whatever scope you have. For example

```
$a = $b + 5;
echo $a;
```

will print *5* because in this case $b will be interpreted as beeing 0.

I hope this will help
Jerome

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no.

Long answer, noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.

But seriously, you *can* refer to it, it just won't do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how strict your warnings on you can call an undeclared variable as much as you want. However until you assign it a value it won't have a value.

Answer (score 0):

No, the execution goes down the file. You can use a function though, to call later on once the variable has been defined. For example:

```
<?php
function meow() {
    echo $kitty_noise;
}
?>
```

And then later on down the file...

```
<?php
$kitty_noice = 'meowwwwww!';
meow();
?>
```

Horrible example....